# How to fix position of scroll bar to bottom in DataGridView?

Tags: vb.net-2010

I am using Visual Studio 2010 and using Visual basic language and Service based database.

I am working on Database and trying to import data from database to DataGridView in windows forms in running mode of the application. I have three columns in database i.e ID, NAME, MARKS. Also, I have three search boxes in windows forms with the same names. The code for displaying data to DataGridView from Database is written in the event of windows forms which display all the rows of database in DataGridView whenever application starts running. I have one "Add Row " button in windows form whose event Handler contains code for adding data to database. In running mode of application, whenever I press "add button" then new row is addded to the database and also displays on the DataGridView. The newly entered row in database contains all the data that was entered in search boxes in running mode of the application.

Now the problem is that whenever new row is inserted to database and is displayed to the DataGridView, the scroll bar moves up which I don't want at all. Although, the DataGridView contain all the rows that were added later but it shows only specific number of rows of the database unless scroll bar is moved downward.

Please help me to get me out of this problem. I would be very thankful.

Waiting for your response,

Regards,
tariq.1000

[DataGridView and Search boxes pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6LmSH.png)